# Running Spring Boot app with custom key store from IntelliJ - "No such file or directory" for key store path

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, ide, keystore

I have a Spring Boot (Maven) app which I run as "jar" this way:

```
java  -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore='/path/to/transport_keystore.jks' -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword='xxx' -jar app-1.1.0.jar
```

It works perfectly fine this way.

I need to run this application via IntelliJ (for debugging), so I setup "Run/Debug Configurations":

[IntelliJ config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4zKK.png)

When I run it from IntelliJ, I've got: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: '/path/to/transport_keystore.jks' (No such file or directory)" exception error, so app cannot see custom keystore.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: enable ssl-debug then compare outputs between those.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to use "'" in IntelliJ:

`-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore='/path/to/transport_keystore.jks'`

works fine with jar running from CLI, but not in IntelliJ.

For IntelliJ this one is fine:

`-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/transport_keystore.jks`